# Cosa significa "bisogna striderci" in questo contesto?

Tags: verbs, meaning

Alla fine del libro *Il giorno della civetta* c'è una nota di Leonardo Sciascia nella quale si può leggere:

> Gli Stati Uniti d'America possono avere, nella narrativa e 
>   nei films, generali imbecilli, giudici corrotti e poliziotti farabutti. Anche l'Inghilterra, 
>   la Francia (almeno fino ad oggi), la Svezia e così via. L'Italia non né ha mai avuti, 
>   non ne ha, non ne avrà mai. Cosi è. E bisogna, come dice Giusti di quegli ambasciatori cui Barnabò Visconti fece ingollare una bolla, cartapecora e piombi di sigillo, **bisogna striderci**.

Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stridere) ho visto che il verbo "stridere" ha il senso figurato seguente:

> **2.** fig. Produrre un effetto di dissonanza, di discordanza, di contrasto: *colori che, messi accanto, stridono; è un quadro che, in questo ambiente, stride per l’audacia della rappresentazione; la colonna sonora stride un po’ con il contenuto del film*.

In altri dizionari ho trovato definizioni simili. Tuttavia, questo non sembra avere molto senso nel contesto del passaggio sopra citato. Nella stessa voce del Treccani ho trovato anche questo:

> **3**. Nell’uso fam. tosc., soffocare l’espressione della propria rabbia, del proprio scontento: *ha dovuto s. per due anni sotto i padroni*.

Questa definizione avrebbe più senso nel brano precedente, ma non sono sicura che sia questo il significato adatto perché appare come un toscanismo di uso familiare. Anche nel [De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/stridere) ho trovato un'accezione simile, che appare anche come toscanismo, ma non ho trovato questo senso del verbo "stridere" in altri dizionari che ho consultato. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: potreste spiegarmi cosa significa "bisogna striderci" nel testo precedente?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sciascia si riferisce a un libro di Giuseppe Giusti, [“Illustrazioni dei proverbi toscani”](http://www.proverbi-italiani.org/pdf/Illustrazioni.pdf), alla voce XIX, “Ambasciatore non porta pena”

> Papa Urbano V, avendo guerra nel 1370 con Bernabò Visconti Signore di Milano, uomo spregiatore e violento, lo scomunicò com’era d’uso, e gli mandò le Bolle d’interdizione per mezzo del Cardinale di Belforte e dell’Abate di Farfa. Bernabò fece finta di prenderla in buona parte, finchè nel congedarli giunto con essi sul ponte del Naviglio di mezzo, si fermò a un tratto, e disse risoluto: — Signori, volete mangiare o volete bere? — i Legati sorpresi non sapevano cosa si rispondere: ma Bernabò insistendo più minaccioso che mai: — Vi dico, perdio, se volete mangiare o se volete bere: non vi lascerò andare senza che abbiate o mangiato o bevuto in modo da ricordarvi di me. Trovandosi lì in mezzo alle guardie, e vedendosi l’acqua sotto, uno di loro, vinto lo sbigottimento, rispose: - Tant’acqua davanti non fa voglia di bere; mangeremo. — Ebbene, disse Bernabò, ecco le Bolle, non s’esce di qui senza averle mangiate, cartapecora, corda, piombo, ogni cosa: e bisognò striderci.

Leggendo il brano, sembra proprio che il significato sia quello del toscanismo “soffocare l'espressione della propria rabbia”.

Comment: In bocca a Giuseppe Giusti mi sembra naturale che si tratti di un toscanismo.

Answer (score 2):

In un'altra opera del Giusti, [*I discorsi che corrono*](https://archive.org/stream/poesiedigiusepp00morlgoog/poesiedigiusepp00morlgoog_djvu.txt) si può leggere:

> I DISCORSI CHE CORRONO
>
> Un'altra, sciorinandosi 
>   Fuori con un pretesto;
>   E un'altra, sullo
>   stendere,  
>   Andando via più presto.
>
> Poi la fede del medico  
>   Ogni quindici giorni; 
>  I bagni; un mese d'aria 
>  Qui per questi
>   dintorni;
>
> Via, tra ninnoli e nannoli, 
>   E' si potea campare. 
>   
> Ora? **bisogna striderci** 
>   
>  volere o volare.
>
> Eccoli là che sgobbano 
>  Piantati a tavolino; 
>  E li coir orologio, 
>   E diciotto di vino.

e nelle spiegazioni si può leggere:

> Diciotto, ecc. É modo proverbiale usato a significare che sopra una
>   data cosa non si può transigere in  alcun modo, e tien luogo delle
>   frasi bisogna striderci, non c'è  modo d'uscirne e simili; e si dice
>   anche sette di vino.

Questo a conferma della risposta di @egreg per cui bisogna striderci significa che è necessario soffocare la propria rabbia e farsene una ragione.